# Постройка башенки

Tags: c#, строки, if, for, int

Столкнулся с такой задачкой: Построить Башню по следующему приведенному аргументу: количеству этажей (`integer` и `always` больше 0)
Пример башен:

```
[
  '  *  ',     -> 3 этажа
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
]
```

```
[
  '     *     ', 
  '    ***    ',   -> 6 этажей
  '   *****   ', 
  '  *******  ', 
  ' ********* ', 
  '***********'
]
```

Входная переменная данной функции `nFloors` - количество этажей

```
public class Kata
{
  public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < nFloors; i++)
    {
      //Я не могу понять как обращаться к элементам строки(если это можно назвать строкой) таким образом - чтобы строилась башенка
    }
    return new string[0];
  }
}
```

Что вообще происходит - даётся число этажей, `nFloors`, учитывая его значение производиться заполнение

```
string.Join(",", new [] { "*" }), string.Join(",", Kata.TowerBuilder(1)));
```

Или

```
string.Join(",", new [] { " * ", "***" }), string.Join(",", Kata.TowerBuilder(2)));
```

У меня ещё очень мало опыта в языке C#. Я никак не могу понять:

1. Как надо обращаться к этажам башенки.
2. Как их поставить друг на друга, чтобы вернуть новое значение строки(если это можно назвать строкой).

Если требуется больше информации для понимания - могу предоставить ещё!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле задача не из самых лёгких. Если вы новичок,советую почитать про динамические типы данных, List и т.д. Но эту задачу можно сделать и обычным динам. массивом. Нам просто нужно завести массив строк, и в каждый элемент класть новую строку, которую мы делаем по заданным правилам. (пробелы, *, пробелы). Вот код решения.Советую хорошо разобраться, а не просто сдать решение:

```
public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
        {
            string[] Result = new string[nFloors]; //Массив строк, который мы будем выводить.
            string String_to_Add = string.Empty; // строка, которую мы собираемся добавлять.
            int counter = nFloors;//Сколько пробелов нам нужно будет ставить
            for (int i = 0; i < nFloors; i++)
            {
                String_to_Add = new string(' ', counter - 1); //Добавляем кол-во пробелов, сколько нужно на данной стадии построения
                String_to_Add = String_to_Add + new string('*', ((i + 1) * 2) - 1); //Добавляем "*". Высчитываем по такой формуле,потому что нам нужно сначала 1, потом 3, 5, 7 , и т.д. 
                String_to_Add = String_to_Add + new string(' ', counter - 1); // Добавляем пробелы в конец. 
                counter--;
                Result[i] = String_to_Add;// Добавляем в массив строк очередную строку.
            }

            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: лучше бы вместо конкатенации использовали `StringBuilder` – слишком много "жрёте" за 1 вызов метода.